# Can the reporting person on a SEC Form 4 choose to break down the stock transactions (Table I) whichever way they want?

Tags: stocks, sec

Looking at a [SEC Form 4's Table I](http://d18rn0p25nwr6d.cloudfront.net/CIK-0001706946/3446c953-1a2b-4a27-a42f-d4277382b8bc.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201217010639/http://d18rn0p25nwr6d.cloudfront.net/CIK-0001706946/3446c953-1a2b-4a27-a42f-d4277382b8bc.pdf)):

[image]

I see that many transactions were made 2020-12-14, and they were grouped into 2 rows in the table (according to the documents, the first row corresponds to shares that were "sold in multiple transactions at price ranging from $26.38 to $27.38" and the second row corresponds to shares that were "sold in multiple transactions at price ranging from $27.39 to $27.78").

I wonder whether the reporting person on a [SEC Form 4](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/form4.asp) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201217010801/https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/form4.asp)) can choose to break down the stock transactions (Table I) whichever way they want, do they have to some rules? E.g., if the reporting person made 2 transactions on the same day but x hours apart and/or with the price/stoch difference of y USD, can they still report it as 1 transaction?

I'm guessing that one cannot group transactions from different date into one row, but I wonder whether there are other reporting rules.

Comment: 53.439 million dollars of stock were sold on 12/14/20.  What difference does it make to you or anyone else if it is reported as two sales with their respective prices or as one sale at an average cost per share?  It's still the same dollar  amount of proceeds.

Comment: @BobBaerker trying to understand how reporting works

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, you need more entertaining hobbies. :)

Comment: @gaefan I didn't adapt well to the covid shelter at home orders :-(